# Functions for fixed-point iteration on a nonlinear system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, fixed-point-iteration

> Given this system of nonlinear equations, solve them by fixed-point iteration starting from $(1,-1,1)$:
>   $$\begin{align}
> 9xy+y^2+3z+18&=0\tag1\\
> x^2+12xy-yz+33&=0\tag2\\
> 5x-4yz+z^2-26&=0\tag3\end{align}$$

How can I choose $3$ functions $f, g, h$  satisfying ,$ x=f(x,y,z), \ y=g(x,y,z) \ and \ z=h(x,y,z). $

Comment: yes , you are right ,in the 3rd equation power of z is 2

Comment: any help is appreciating

Comment: partial derivatives with respect to x, y,z

Comment: For your first function, I take$ |\partial f_{1x} \times f(1,-1,1)| +   |\partial f_{1y} \times f(1,-1,1)| +  |\partial f_{1z} \times f(1,-1,1)| $and it is greater than $1$. Can you provide more details of how you did it?

Comment: yes you are  absolutely  right, my calculation was wrong, so any other way can i solve the problem with different choice ? can you you suggest f1,f2,f3

Comment: yes it is to be solved by fixed point iteration

Comment: i am not sure, but it was given to me   as question to solve